# How to turn off icon gloss effect in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, xcode5

I'm making app and I'm try to turn off icon gloss effect. Earlier in Xcode 4 it was able to turn off icon gloss effect by turn on "Prerenderred" checkbox. Now when i want to use Assets catalog i have to edit .plist file. And i did it. I add key `Icon already includes gloss effects` and set to `YES` but effect is still on icon. How to disable this effect correctly in new Xcode?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Irrespective of the fact that you're talking about a iOS release that's covered by an NDA, the fact that it's a *developer preview* means that it's by no means complete, so the fact that certain things aren't working shouldn't be a surprise. Please check the Apple discussion forum for information on this issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries - the forums are back up now, so it's worth checking to see if this is a known issue/whether there are workarounds.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple when you use `.xcassets (Assets)`. What you have to do is to select your AppIcon collection and on the right pane (Inspector) select `Pre-rendered icon`. and that's it.

Comment: this worked for me in iOS 7. But when i start in iOS 6.0.1 (3gs) my app icon stay with a black corner. How to solve it?

Comment: Not enough upvotes in the world for this. I was going through all the old Info.plist methods and pulling my hair out. For @JuanMunhoesJunior (I'm sure you figured it out), but clear your build folder.

Answer (score 13):

Just as Tomasz Szulc described:

1. In the `Project Navigator`, Click on project name
2. In the `App Icons` section, press `Use Asset Catalog`
3. Click import
4. Click on the small arrow next to the combo box
5. In the `Attribute Inspector`, check `iOS icon is pre-rendered`

Hope that helps.

Comment: No need to repost another person's answer.  Just give him a +1

Comment: I did. Although, I wanted to describe the same answer in easier language.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the icon from the simulator, clean the build, and try once again to run.