# How to turn off icon gloss effect in Xcode 5 when using assets?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, xcode5

How to turn off icon gloss effect in Xcode 5 when using assets.
 I stuck in  icon.

Comment: chk this answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187089/how-to-turn-off-icon-gloss-effect-in-xcode-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple when you use .xcassets (Assets). What you have to do is to select your AppIcon collection and on the right pane (Inspector) select Pre-rendered icon. and that's it.

1. In the Project Navigator, Click on project name
2. In the App Icons section, press Use Asset Catalog
3. Click import
4. Click on the small arrow next to the combo box

In the Attribute Inspector, check iOS icon is pre-rendered